# Rationale for removing cronie-anacron

Tags: centos, nessus

My Nessus scanner reports that I need to remove cronie-anacron. What is the rationale for this?

The Nessus output is:

```
3.3.b(2) Disable Anacron  
checking that the anacron RPM package is not installed

Reference
RHEL7 SSGv0.1.3.3.b

The local RPM is newer than cronie-anacron-0.0.0 (cronie-anacron-1.4.11 )  
References  
800-53|CM-7
```

Comment: The report should have some justification as to why it suggests this - could be something like an outdated version, an unused package, or a false positive. You'll need to provide more details for anyone to help though.

Comment: What details would be helpful?

Comment: I think you have removed a lot more from the report. Nessus usually explains the reasons.

Comment: Nope. I've added the 2 other sentences, just for completeness. Not much value added there.